# Computed columns in SQL Server referencing another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

To help explain my question I'll explain a little bit of the problem.  We have a database of customers, including a history of their addresses (i.e. every address update inserts a new row into the address table and we have views that pull the latest information for reporting on screen and printed reports).

User requirement for a new search is that we show their current address (if we have one on file) on search results to determine that they are indeed finding the correct client.

We have reached a performance hit by running a left join to a view in our returned search results, so this is where the question comes in.

Our first thought was to store a copy of the latest address for display only purposes in our customer table, but we were concerned at how to keep this data updated.  We wondered if a computed column could be built on a scalar function to query our view and have it persisted, or if triggers were our only option.

Am I barking up the wrong tree entirely by looking at ways of getting around this slowness, should I be investigating addressing the database tuning in some way to optimize the search instead?

Thanks in advance,
Wesley

edit: query is as shown:

```
Select 
    Clients.ClientID,
    Clients.LastName,
    Clients.FirstName,
    Clients.PreferredName,
    PrimaryDeliveryCity as City,
    PrimaryDeliveryPostalCode as PostalCode,
    DateOfBirth,
    ClientNumber
FROM 
    Clients LEFT JOIN v_LatestClientAddressHistoryRecord 
    ON Clients.ClientID = v_LatestClientAddressHistoryRecord.ClientID
WHERE
    ClientNumber like @ClientNumber + '%'
```

Indeed the query does have %, however not on the joined table.

Clients has 50,000 records, view has similar but slightly less, base address table has 200,000

Edit #2:

```
SELECT ClientAddressHistoryRecords.*
FROM
dbo.ClientAddressHistoryRecords INNER JOIN dbo.v_LatestClientAddressHistoryRecordID 
ON dbo.ClientAddressHistoryRecords.ClientID = dbo.v_LatestClientAddressHistoryRecordID.ClientID 
AND
dbo.ClientAddressHistoryRecords.ClientAddressHistoryRecordID = dbo.v_LatestClientAddressHistoryRecordID.MaxClientAddressHistoryRecordID
```

and the v_LatestClientAddressHistoryRecordID view

```
SELECT     MAX(ClientConsentHistoryRecordID) AS MaxClientConsentHistoryRecordID, ClientID
FROM         dbo.ClientConsentHistoryRecords
GROUP BY ClientID
```

Comment: Show us your query with the outer join please. Does it have `LIKE '%...` ?

Comment: If your stored function references another table, you **cannot** persist the computed column, unfortunately....

Comment: You could make an indexed view for this, however, to persist the data.

Comment: @gbn - updated with query, what's the question behind the LIKE %?

Comment: How about the code for v_LatestClientAddressHistoryRecord ?

Comment: @JNK - for the indexed view, i would basically have the structure of my select results including the left join, and then do all searching then from this view?  We would take a performance hit then when saving to any of the underlying tables correct, as the view would get recalculated? (i'm assuming also that this would be more acceptable in our environment)

Comment: @Wes - basically.  Indexed views are really better for things like aggregates though, which is what I thought you were using for  your calculation

Comment: @JNK - so if it were you in this position, which of the now 3 options would you choose.  Keep a history and a "latest" table, use a trigger to update the clients table when addresses are updated, or make an indexed view?

Comment: @Wes - probably Aaron's idea for the trigger.  It would resolve your speed issue on lookups most effectively which sounds like the primary concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be an `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` that inserts all inserts/updates into a history table (each as its own row), and merges all inserts/updates into an active table (with the only row for a customer being the most current row). Now you point your active queries at the active table, and if you need the history, you write that query to go fetch it from the archive table. Yes, you have two copies of the active rows, but assuming the speed issue is due to there being a large % of old addresses sticking around, this might be ok.

Comment: That is a new idea we had not thought of.  I would imagine that would work fairly well, if we need latest address look in the latest address table, otherwise look in address history for the full story.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was thinking. It allows you to separate the old and new data without heavily impacting the existing application, in fact you may be able to do it without changing the application at all (this depends on whether you control data access via stored procedures or middle tier/DAL, or just let the app run DML/SELECT statements directly).

Answer (score 1):

Computed columns or triggers could provide a solution to this.  You're not barking up a wrong tree with those ideas.

However, one thing to consider is whether or not this could be handled through scheduled maintenance ("jobs").

If your expired addresses don't factor in to your day-to-day transactions, then you could periodically (depending on the speed of your data growth -- maybe once per year, month, week...) move them out into a different table (or different database, etc.).  This would keep your transaction table smaller, and speed-up your queries accordingly.

The benefit to a `job`, over `computed columns` or `triggers`, would be 1) that the work done by the database would be less, and 2) the work could be done at a more convenient time.  Consider that with Computed columns and triggers, the work is done at the same time the CRUD operation takes place.  Scheduled maintenance, on the other hand, could be scheduled to occur off-peak (like 2am, or whatever it works out to for your operation).

Comment: A related option would be to fix the table that has the addresses in it to make the view faster.  I'm guessing OP has something like a datetime field he is sorting by to find the `MAX(effectivedate)` per user or something.  Just add a `BIT` that indicates a record is active and filter on that.

Comment: JNK - pulling max on the primary key for the address table based on client which is a foreign key to the client table.

Comment: kuru - we did mull over that idea as well, but are unsure that we can allow for a delay in the data displayed (as in using the task to update customers table), it's still an option for us as well. The thought of thinning out the records in the address table after they are not the most current is also a good one however for other reporting we don't believe it is a possible option (or would add significantly to complexity for reporting)

Comment: @wes - can you add a simpler view to join on that only has the address logic in it?  It sounds like the view you use now is fairly complicated if it runs for long.

Comment: @JNK - The view is fairly simple, we do a max on address id group by client id, then we join that view back to the address table to grab details to report back.  The search runs slower, 3 seconds as compared to almost instant.  Doing an inner join to the table makes our search take 1 second in comparison, but then does not return clients without an address on file. Searching has been deemed of utmost importance.  A large portion of lookups are performed with a customer on the phone, so timeliness is key.